# Does using prototypes in JavaScript have any real world advantages?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, function, prototype

I just finished Doug Crockford's [The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748), and he offers three different ways to go about inheritance: [emulation](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) of the classical model, prototype-based inheritance, and functional inheritance.

In the latter, he creates a function, a factory of sorts, which spits out objects augmented with desired methods that build upon other objects; something along the lines of:

```
var dog = function(params) {
    // animal is the 'super class' created
    // the same way as the dog, and defines some
    // common methods
    var that = animal(params);
    that.sound = 'bark';
    that.name = function () {};
    return that;
}
```

Since all objects created this way will have a reference to the same functions, the memory footprint will be much lower than using when using the `new` operator, for instance. The question is, would the prototype approach offer any advantages in this case? In other words, are object prototypes somehow 'closer to the metal' that provide performance advantages, or are they just a convenience mechanism?

EDIT: I'll simplify the question. Prototypes vs. their emulation through object composition. So long as you don't require all object instances to get updated with new methods which is a convenience offered only by prototypes, are there any advantages to using prototypes in the first place?

I emailed Doug Crockford, and he had this to say:

> [Using the functional approach above vs. prototypes] isn't that much memory. If you have a huge number of objects times a huge number of methods, then you might want to go prototypal. But memories are abundant these days, and only an extreme application is going to notice it.
>
> Prototypes can use less memory, but can have slightly slower retrieval, particularly if the chains are very long. But generally, this is not noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

The instances *don't* all reference the same functions etc. Each call to "dog" will create a new "name" function instance.

Comment: Hmm. You're right, I didn't see that somehow. Isn't that terrible, then? :)

Comment: The question stands though: do prototypes offer any advantage, compared to simply referencing the same functions from within multiple objects?

Comment: Well you save a lot of memory by not having separate copies of utility functions for each instance.

Comment: @mitjak: I don't know if any JS implementation does it, but some languages can, in this case just (transparently) create _one_ static instance of the function created inside `dog`, and each time you call `dog`, it will just give a new reference to that function. If it is imperative that each function have a different identity, this function may be generated each time, but probably has a tiny overhead, but each of those generated functions will have a reference to the same bytecode (and possibly different closure). In any case, the overhead is probably insignificant.

Comment: @Pointy My code was a bad example. Suppose the references were maintained correctly so that every instance references the same 'core' object. How about then? All I'm interested in is whether prototypes provide any performance advantage, as their behaviour can be emulated to a certain degree.

Comment: How much of a "performance advantage" are you looking for?  A modern Javascript engine is going to be performance-tuned to support the ways that the language is most commonly used. Trying to do something quirky is probably not a long-term good strategy.

Comment: Well, any and all. I think I am attempting to ask multiple questions within the original posting, but it should have basically boiled down to: is building objects with prototypes any faster than composing objects with properties and methods of other objects, thereby creating references instead of copies of those properties and methods? Memory footprint wise the approaches seem to be approximately equivalent.

Comment: I've emailed Doug Crockford, and updated the original question with his response. I'm still not satisfied with the answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many opinions about this, and Crockford's isn't necessarily the right one.

The main disadvantage to modifying the prototypes is that it may make it harder to work with other javascript libraries.

But the disadvantage of Crockford's functional way of creating classes is that you can't add a method or field to all instances of a type as easily.

See Closure: The Definitive Guide for some critical comments on Crockford's view about classes and inheritance in javascript:
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781449381882/I_sect1_d1e29990#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzODE4ODIvNTE0

Libraries like Dojo, Google Closure Library (which seems to copy Dojo's style), and perhaps YUI have their own class system that seems to be a good middle ground.  I like Dojo's system probably the best because it has support for Mixins, unlike Closure.  Some other class systems not tied to gui toolkits include Joose, JS.Class, and JavascriptMVC (check out last one esp. if using jquery).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but a question about this:
"The main disadvantage to modifying the prototypes is that it may make it harder to work with other javascript libraries."

Why would I be modifying prototypes of the built-in objects? I'm mostly talking about prototypes of objects I myself create.

Comment: @mitjak modifying the prototypes of built-ins is somewhat popular; see for example the Prototype library, which does it with wild abandon.

Comment: It is popular, but that's not exactly what I'm trying to find out about here.

Answer (score 0):

I once created a GUI that was backed by a class that didn't have great event-based support for the information it needed. The GUI implemented a generic interface where an *instance* of that class is passed in, so I cannot inherit from that class, so I did something similar to prototype-based inheritance, I created a proxy object that wraps the instance of that class when it's passed to my GUI. The proxy intercepts methods of interest that mutate state, and report them as events. The entire GUI then revolved around using these events.

In this case, it would have just been annoying to create a separate class that wraps the passed in instance and reproduces the same interface. This would actually have lead to *more* overhead (not that it matters) due to creating all the redundant functions.

There was simply no other viable alternative. The only alternatives were:

1. Create an object that composes the object passed to the GUI (like I mentioned above). This object would then reproduce every function in the original class to implement the same interface, and add events, so it's effectively just the same as the proxy object way.
2. Have the GUI track state mutation in its passed in object. This would have been *a pain* and bug prone.